# Qt - Default Alignment for addWidget in VBoxLayout

Tags: python, qt, layout, alignment

I'm struggling with the Alignment-Parameter at the addWidget(widget, stretch, alignment) method from a QVBoxlayout.

I'm adding a QTableview to my layout:

Without an alignment argument everything works fine - my tableview fills the entire space in the layout.

Now, I want to know, what is the default alignment used, so that I can add that to my method-call. The documentation says, without an alignment argument, the default-alignment-argument is zero. But when I call addWidget with "0" as my alignment-argument, pycharm is complaining about wrong type, int instead of Qt:: Alignment...

Answer (score 3):

The good part of opensource software is that you can [take a look at the source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qboxlayout.h.html#_ZN10QBoxLayout9addWidgetEP7QWidgeti6QFlagsIN2Qt13AlignmentFlagEE), the code is:

```
void addWidget(QWidget *, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = Qt::Alignment());
```

So call your the addWidget method with the equivalent of `Qt::Alignment()` as the last argument:

```
yourLayout.addWidget(yourWidget, 0, Qt.Alignment())  # Python
yourLayout->addWidget(yourWidget, 0, {});           // C++
```